# VS code is showing file directory error even after many changes

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, mingw

I use vs code in for my college and make multiple source files which I save in a folder on my desktop and VS code and mingw is installed in c folder so every time I try to run my code it gives out this eroor:

```
gcc: error: string: No such file or directory
gcc: error: functions.c: No such file or directory
gcc: error: functions: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

My terminal directory is showing the same address as the file location:

```
PS C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\nf\code>
```

But it's still giving this error.

I wanna know which files should I change to where because I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, I tried it on a different pc with same settings and I still get the same issue.

The files are saved in a folder with multiple folders all of which contain different files mostly in C but a few python & java, I doubt that might be an issue.

Comment: how are you compiling your program? What's the full file structure? Can you provide some code?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw